# Como remover um constraint SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tendo um problema para remover uma constraint de uma tabela.

Objetivo é excluir a constraint para excluir uma tabela.

O problema é: Eu tenho uma tabela Rendimento que esta associada a Rendimento extra.
Essa tabela Rendimento esta com FK_COD_RENDA_EXTRA.

ALTER TABLE RENDIMENTO_EXTRA
DROP CONSTRAINT [COD_RENDA_EXTRA]

porém retorna a mensagem de Erro

"Mensagem 3728, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 2
'COD_RENDA_EXTRA' não é uma restrição.
Mensagem 3727, Nível 16, Estado 0, Linha 2
Não foi possível cancelar a restrição. Consulte os erros anteriores."

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Provavelmente o nome da constraint está errado, você está se referênciando a FK e não a constraint propriamente dita. No seu print, abaixo da coluna VAL_SALARIO_FIXO clique no `[+]Restrições` la será listado as constraints

Comment: Caique, realmente a constraint estava com o nome errado, o nome correto era [FK_RENDIMEN_REFERENCE_RENDIMEN].
Por isso não estava localizando. 
Vlw

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi sua constraint é **[FK_COD_RENDA_EXTRA]**  na tabela **Rendimento**.
Altere o nome e a tabela da constraint para realizar o drop corretamente, já que este tem que ser feito na tabela que contém a FK.

```
ALTER TABLE [Rendimento] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_COD_RENDA_EXTRA]
```

Comment: Andyson, consegui aqui. Vlw pela ajuda